# How to select an option on Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
<template>
 <select class="form-control mt-1" @change="selectUser">
  <option >select user</option>
  <option v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index" {{user.first_name}}</option>
 </select>
</template>

<script>
selectUser(event){
 if(event.target.selectedIndex != 0){
   this.index = event.target.selectedIndex-1
   this.selectedUsers.push(this.users[this.index])
   this.users.splice(this.index, 1)
  }              
}
</script>
```

The idea of this script is that when you select an option it gets removed and added to another array of objects and it disappears from the select list.
I want when this happened, the first option to get selected back again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `v-model` to get the selected item from `<select>`

```
<select v-model="selected">
        ......
</select>
```

and then use it this way:

`<span>Selected: {{ selected }}</span>`

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to have :

- a options and a selectedOption in the data.
- A availableOptions as computed options, with options.filter(o => o !== this.selectedOption)
- Bind the select with a v-model=selectedOption
- bind the  with the avaiableOptions